# Replace a specific characters after the occurrence of a string using regex.replace

Tags: c#, regexp-replace

I need to replace after 0x all S to 5. The S are not always at same position, but they are always after 0x.

Example string:
Sunny day Since yesterday 0xS4321S3S

Should be
Sunny day Since yesterday 0x54321535

I have tried regex.replace pattern (?<=0x)S, but this just matches the 0x5.

Comment: I would do a substring search for the last `0x` in your string, then replace all `S` characters individually after that point. You don't necessarily need a regex for this if you only operate on the substring. This gets more complicated for an `example 0xS12231S1 like 0x4S124S31 this`. Hence, you should be clear about the totality of your input. A good way is a lot of input examples that showcase the edge cases/potential variations involved. Be wary of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): there's more than one way to solve a problem, so ask about the problem instead of the solution

Comment: `(?<=0x.*)S` should work

Comment: This also works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET regex engine supports a lookbehind assertion with an infinite quantifier. If you don't want to cross matching spaces, you can use `\S*` to match optional non whitespace characters.

```
(?<=0x\S*)S
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y8KWUN/1)